# Serve http server behind an Apache https Proxy

Tags: apache, mod-proxy

It seems that it is possible to get Apache server to Proxy and Manage SSL handshake on https requests and service them as 'http' thru another server behind it.

I have configured an apache server for ProxyPass using following configuration

```
SSLProxyEngine On
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8081/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8081/
```

I am able to get all all traffic to the apache server that is listening to port 8080 direct and serve by the localhost:8081 server so

```
http://localhost:8080/hi is being correctly served by http://localhost:8081/hi
```

However the following does not work :

```
http**s**://localhost:8080/hi to be served by http://localhost:8081/hi
```

Apache is trying to pass the https:// traffic to the 8081 server, without managing the SSL handshake.

Answer (score 1):

Your Apache listener on port 8080 is an `http` listener, not an `https` listener.  You can't handle both types of traffic on the same port.  If you want to handle SSL traffic, you'll need to set up a new context on another port with `SSLEngine On` and all the other normal SSL configuration (certificate, key, etc).

[This question](https://serverfault.com/questions/25423/apache-virtualhost-with-mod-proxy-and-ssl) has one version of this configuration.

Also [this post](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/08/08/setting-up-apache-as-a-ssl-front-end-for-play/).

Comment: Thank you for your quick response !.  So any pointers on how do I go about doing that ? (Sorry I am new to this and have gone thru the documents but nothing obvious).

Comment: The two links in the answer have pretty much exactly what you need.  They include example configurations.

Comment: Great. Let me take a look. You are a saviour !